# Passing object to linq result

Tags: c#, linq, list

I get an item from the list to manuplate it.

```
App.CurrentQuestion = App.AllQuestionList[dataSourceRowIndex];
```

After manuplations I save new data to database and get back from database into App.CurrentQuestion, so App.CurrentQuestion's list reference breaks. I want to update list and trying to focus selected item by linq

```
App.AllQuestionList
    .Where(q => q.qID == App.CurrentQuestion.qID)
    .FirstOrDefault() = App.CurrentQuestion;
```

but I get an error like "***The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer***"

I can use this method

```
for (int i = 0; i < App.AllQuestionList.Count; i++)
{
    if (App.AllQuestionList[i].qID == App.CurrentQuestion.qID)
    {
        App.AllQuestionList[i] = App.CurrentQuestion;
        break;
    }
}
```

but looking for an alternative method. Or is there any faster method?

Comment: Im guessing the OP meant `Passing` as `assing` does indeed sound painful :)

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of Linq in this case

Comment: @Jamiec based on the question I think he is referring to assigning

Comment: @DavidPilkington - you could be right. I'll leave it for now and let the OP update if im wrong

Comment: A LINQ `.Where(...)` returns an `IEnumerable` which allows you to iterate through a readonly view of the original collection. So you can't change stuff.

Comment: where are you showing the items of the list(listbox,combobox,etc..),how do you get the index to get the desired item from the list....?

Comment: @terrybozzio I list data into a gridview and index is gridview's focusedrow index.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to do anything, since it's by reference.

```
App.CurrentQuestion = App.AllQuestionList[dataSourceRowIndex];
```

Whatever change you make in `App.CurrentQuestion` should be reflected in the `App.AllQuestionList`

```
App.AllQuestionList[App.AllQuestionList.IndexOf(App.AllQuestionList.
    .Where(q => q.qID == App.CurrentQuestion.qID)
    .First())] = App.CurrentQuestion;
```

Edit: you can just use the IndexOf to find the index of the object you wanted to find by LINQ query

Comment: Yes, I thought it is reference type and data should be already synchronized. But I forgot to tell; I get data from database after save operation so reference can not continue.